# Dual of the space of bounded functions on the unit hypercube

Tags: dual-spaces

Which is the dual of the space $\ell^\infty([0,1]^d)$? Does the dual of such space consists of a set of functionals $\phi$ admitting the representation

$$
\phi(f)=\int_0^1 f\circ g(u) \psi_\phi(u) du,  \quad f \in \ell^\infty([0,1]^d),
$$

with $g:(0,1)\mapsto[0,1]^d$, $\psi_\phi  \in L^1((0,1), \mathcal{B}((0,1)), \lambda)$, and $\mathcal{B}((0,1))$ and $\lambda$ denoting the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and the Lebesgue measure on the unit interval, respectively? If the above representation is too specific, does the dual consists of a set of functionals that can be expressed as integrals of elements $f$ of $\ell^\infty([0,1]^d)$ on appropriate spaces with repsect to the Lebesgue measure of such spaces?

Comment: No, that representation fails even for the case $d=1$.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you know any condition under which $\phi(f)$, with $\phi$ a continuous functional, can be given an integral representation?

Comment: Elements of the duals of spaces like $l^{\infty}, L^{\infty} (\mu)$ etc have a  known representation only when they are finite dimensional.

Comment: A subspace of the dual of $\ell^\infty([0,1]^d)$ is $\ell^1([0,1]^d)$.  You can think of those functionals as integrals (with respect to a discrete measure).